# Getting a Syntax error on Doctrine CreateQueryBuilder with multiple SELECT

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I have this query below which returns everything as expected.  However, when run I get a doctrine syntax error but I cant pintpoint it.  Is there a special way to add multiple selects in Doctrine?

This is my function.

```
public function summaryReport()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ds')
        ->select('ds.d_id, ds.d_name,
                        SUM(ds.c_email IS NOT NULL) * 100.00 / COUNT(c_number) AS percentage,
                        COUNT(DISTINCT ds.c_number) AS Qualifying_customers,
                        sum(ds.c_email IS not NULL) AS Qualifying_Customers_with_Email')
        ->groupBy('ds.d_id, ds.d_name')
        ->getQuery();
    dd($qb->getDQL());
    return $qb->getResult();
}
```

error I am receiving is

```
 Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'IS'
```

would an addSelect seperate them?

Answer (score 0):

`SUM(ds.c_email IS NOT NULL)` is not correct here.
The SUM function is defined as `"SUM" "(" ["DISTINCT"] StringPrimary ")"`, the condition here is not accepted.

If you want the `NOT NULL` condition to return 1 or 0, you have to use an `IF` function. Ex: `SUM(IF(ds.c_email IS NOT NULL, 1, 0))`

Comment: Thank you Alessandro, this didnt do it for me. The below answer did.

Answer (score 0):

This was the query that passed

```
public function summaryReport()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ds')
        ->select('ds.d_id, ds.d_name,
                        (sum(case  when  ds.c_email IS null then 0 else 1 end))*100/count(ds.c_number) as percentage')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT ds.c_number) AS qualifying')
        ->addSelect('sum(case when ds.c_email IS NULL then 0 else 1 end) AS qualifyingEmail')
        ->groupBy('ds.d_id, ds.d_name')
        ->getQuery();

    return $qb->getResult();
}
```